# Configure launch.json for VSCode to execute PowerShell commands in the debug session

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, runspace

Is it possible to create an entry in the `launch.json`, which executes a PowerShell script or scriptblock, in the **same runspace** as the to-be-launched and debugged script?

The reason is, I would like to reset the runspace (remove variables + background jobs, unload modules etc.) before debugging a script. The "***temporary integrated console***" which was created for that purpose, unfortunately has an [unfixed bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/1263) for over a year now, which prevents interactive debugging in the temporary console and therefore makes it useless to me.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Nope. It is not possible and the bug is still not fixed. There are a few open issues about this on github.

Comment: Unfortunate - hope to see a fix soon!

Comment: It seems that the bug was fixed in March 2020 - https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/1263.